# Laravel Blueprint (or SQL) to DBAL Table

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

Is it possible to turn a Laravel Blueprint class into a DBAL Table class (Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table)? If not, is it possible to turn SQL into a DBAL Schema class?

The goal is to use the DBAL Schema comparator to compare Laravel migration Blueprints or compare a Blueprint directly with an existing table.

Comment: I don't think there are magic methods that will make this easy since laravel `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` does not extend Doctrine classes at all. In fact you don't even need doctrine/dbal installed for it to work.

Comment: @IGP Yeah, though dbal is a soft dependency so I thought there might be an easy way of converting between them.

Comment: I don't think there is. Laravel's Blueprint doesn't keep information about its columns unlike Doctrine's Table, so there's not even a way to access the information you'd need to create a Table class from scratch.

Comment: @IGP Aha, that sucks, the only 2 options will be converting from SQL or just using DBAL instead.